# Error Importing Pages on Oracle APEX 19.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I upgraded both my development and production environment to 19.2, but I faced a strange error, when I tried to export page from development and import it to production. I get the following error when I ran the page:

There is no authentication configured for this application.
Contact your application administrator. Details about this incident are available via debug id "151508".

There is no debug logs on it.

I exported the file as same as always for the last 5 years. No translation was exported Unicode ,format is UTF-8 and The file ty[e is DOS

Is anyone facing this issue like me?

Regards

Comment: check the Authentication schemes in the aplication and what Authentication scheme is set for the page you imported, maybe the page is trying to use an Authentication scheme that doesent exist in PROD

Comment: I'm using the same authentication

Comment: The steps I'd take would be to export the app from prod, examine the script to check that it includes the authentication scheme, import it into dev and test whether importing your page causes the same error or not. I'd try to work out whether the problem exists in the production instance, or with your page export file.

Comment: This error shows when I upgraded from 19.1 to 19.2

Comment: You must have solved this by now. For those of us who are just upgrading now, what was the issue?